# Найти множество ключей в многомерном массиве с одинаковыми значениями

Tags: php

Функция для поиска ключей с одинаковыми значениями в многомерном массиве, 
вывод этих ключей и сравнение значений

Например:
в массиве `$array` присутствует ключи с именами `"rate"(foo)` и `"overallRate"(bar)` (на любом уровне вложенности), Значения ключей `"rate"(foo)` и `"overallRate"(bar)` совпадают. 
Пробовал обходить массив использую рекурсию, но с 3го уровня вложенности значения не возвращает, только выводит значение через `echo`.

```
function processArray($array,$howdeep = 0){
   $howdeep++;

   if (is_array($array)) {
      foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
         if ( $key == "bar") {
            if(!is_array($key)) {
               echo $value . " = уровень вложенности массива : $howdeep </br>";
            }
         }
         processArray($value, $howdeep);
      }
   }
}
```

Пример массива JSON, его я уже перевёл в массив PHP

```
$array = {
  "foo": "Sergey",
  "lastName": "Sauron918",
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "Киевская 1",
    "onetwo": 10001
  },
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "Киевская 13",
    "onelevel": {
      "streetAddress": "Киевская 13",
      "bar": "Sergey"
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На выбор 2 варианта, первый, имхо, проще и понятней но работает дольше, второй чуть быстрее.

**Вариант1**:
Сначала сплющить массив чтобы он стал одномерным, затем отсортировать и получить дубликаты. В качестве ключей в сплющенном массиве используется путь до текущего элемента. В качестве бонуса, можно узнать в каких местах есть повторения.

*Осторожно:* этот вариант не работает если есть ключи содержащие знак ".". С его помощью конкатенируются ключи в пути.

Для того чтобы не нужно было сливать сплющенные массивы полученные с разных уровне вложенности flat_array (результирующий массив) передаётся по ссылке.

```
function flattaning( array $array, &$flat_array = [], $parent_key = '' ): array{
    //эта функция рекурсивно сплющивает массив.
    //   array - массив который нужно сплющить
    //   flat_array - сплющенный массив
    //   parent_key - путь до текущей вложенности

    if( ! $array ) return []; // пустой массив уже достаточно плоский

    foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
        if( is_array( $value ) )
            flattaning( $value, $flat_array, $parent_key.$key."." );
        else
            $flat_array[ $parent_key.$key ] = $value;
    }
    return $flat_array;
}


function get_duplicates( array $flat ): array {
    // функция получения дубликатов из одномерного массива.     

    if( ! $flat ) return []; // в пустом массиве дубликатов нет

    asort( $flat );
    reset( $flat );

    $duplicates = [];

    list( $prev_key, $prev_value ) = each( $flat );
    while( list( $cur_key, $cur_value ) = each( $flat ) ){
        if( $cur_value == $prev_value ){
            echo "duplicate on keys $cur_key and $prev_key, value is $cur_value\n";
            $duplicates[] = $cur_value;
        }
        $prev_value = $cur_value;
        $prev_key = $cur_key;
    }
    array_unique( $duplicates );
    return $duplicates;
}
```

**Вариант 2**: Рекурсивно обходит массив сохраня, знакомые значения и дубликаты в отдельных параметрах. Чтобы не пришлось сливать массивы дубликатов на разных уровнях вложенности, дубликаты передаются по ссылке.
Дубликаты и значения хранятся в массивах в ключах, для ускорения поиска и устранения повторов в дубликатах.

```
function get_duplicates2( $array, $deep = 0, &$known_values = [], &$duplicates = [] ){
    foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
        if( is_array( $value ) ){ // обход вложенного массива
            get_duplicates2( $value, $deep + 1, $known_values, $duplicates );
        } else if( isset( $known_values[ $value ] ) ){ 
            echo "duplicate found on deep $deep, value: $value\n";
            $duplicates[ $value ] = true;
        } else {
            $known_values[ $value ] = true;
        }
    }

    return array_keys( $duplicates );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!

Answer (score 1):

```
function processArray($array, &$result){
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value))
      processArray($value, $result);
    else {
      if (!isset($result[$value])
        $result[$value] = [];
      $result[$value][] = $key;
    }
  }
}
$result = [];
processArray($data, $result);
```

На выходе получится массив `$result` с ключами в виде исходных значений и значениями в виде массива исходных ключей